# Listar por tramo de fechas y horas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy intentando hacer una lista asistencias por tramo de fechas y horas. He formulado este procedimiento almacenado y no me muestra nada

```
create  PROCEDURE  [dbo].[PaListarAsistenciaGeneral]
@FechaInicio date,
@FechaFinal date,
@Hora1 varchar(10),
@Hora2 varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
select 
a.FechaAsistencia,a.DetalleAsistencia
,(p.Nombre+' '+p.ApellidoPaterno+''+p.ApellidoMaterno)Cliente
, CONVERT(char, a.FechaAsistencia, 108) as Hora
 from Asistencia a
inner join DetalleInscripcion di on di.CodInscripcion=a.CodInscripcion and di.CodDisciplinaTipoSuscripcion=a.CodDisciplinaTipoSuscripcion 
inner join Inscripcion i on i.CodInscripcion=di.CodInscripcion
inner join Cliente c on c.CodCliente=i.CodCliente
inner join Persona p on p.CodPersona=c.CodCliente
where  
(CONVERT (char(10), a.FechaAsistencia, 103) between CONVERT (char(10), @FechaInicio , 103) and CONVERT (char(10), @FechaFinal, 103)) 
and
 ((CONVERT (char(10), a.FechaAsistencia, 108)) between CONVERT (char(10), @Hora1, 108)  and CONVERT (char(10), @Hora2, 108))

end
```

La hora lo saco de FechaAsistencia ya que es un campo tipo Datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el tipo final, el de `FechaAsistencia` es un `DateTime` no entiendo bien las conversiones que haces.

Lo lógico sería tener una fecha de inicio y una de fin y hacer algo simple

```
where  a.FechaAsistencia between @FechaInicio AND @FechaFinal
```

Siempre y cuando `@FechaInicio` y `@FechaFinal` fueran parámetros del tipo `DateTime`
Pero si quieres pasar la hora por separado mejor pasarla como un `int` en vez de `varchar`.

Y el `WHERE` de la consulta quedaría

```
where a.FechaAsistencia between @FechaInicio and @FechaFinal
and ((CONVERT (int, a.FechaAsistencia, 108)) between CONVERT (int, @Hora1, 108)  
and CONVERT (int, @Hora2, 108))
```